# How do I only Include one delimiter in C# regex?

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I'm trying to regex out a string that looks like something like this:

```
"x.i.x.m x.i.x.m.ng(ing)"
```

Into an array like this

```
["X", "I", "X", "M", " ", "X", "I", "X", "M", "NG(ING")
```

I've managed to get the space to be includes into to the array, but haven't been able to split the rest by a "." yet. Thanks in advance!

Comment: could you share the regex that you have tried so far? Also the string does not seem to have a space, but the array should include an element for space?

Comment: What is your rule here? This is unclear. Do you want to replace all characters with an `X` until you reach a space, and then upper-case the rest of the characters, unless the character is a period, in which case ignore it?

Comment: @Rizwan M.Tuman Your edit changed OP's expected output. How do you know that's correct?

Comment: I just wanted to help his typo... look he mentioned to split by . thus I have found it logical .. and thought of that as a typo.. but i can change it if you think i am wrong

Comment: I don't think you're wrong. If it wasn't a typo though, that changes what the answer should be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apply this Regex:

```
\.|( +)
```

Explanation:

1. `\.` split by dot
2. `|` or
3. `( +)` split by one or more spaces , but, if we mark it as a capture group then the regex split will also include this into the array. Thus come the capture group ()

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/tSYfWO/1/)

You may try this: ( [run the sample here](https://ideone.com/PF8JNk) )

```
string sentence = @"x.i.x.m x.i.x.m.ng(ing)";
string[] segs= Regex.Split(sentence, @"\.|( +)");
foreach (string value in segs)
{
        Console.WriteLine(value.ToUpper());
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I ended up using @"\.|(\s)", and it does exactly what I'm looking for. I was trying to find something like | <- that to do multiple expressions on one string, but I couldn't find it. Thanks again!

Comment: Glad to know that it worked for you but please note that \s means not only space but newline, tab , carriage return as well.. if you don't want to split by those except space then you should not use \s and + ensures that, if there is consecutive spaces then that be dimmed as a single unit... But that depends on your business logic

Comment: I would also like to split by those, which is why I changed it to use \s. All whitespace is skipped over essentially, and added to a final string, without manipulation, but the rest of the characters are manipulated.